# Spring MVC Resources

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to link my static elements in with Spring MVC using the resources tag - what I am not able to figure out is where to place them.

I am publishing my links as -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/elements.css">
```

I have placed the files under - 
WebContent/resources/css/elements.css

The resources tag I am using in my servlet is -

```
<mvc:resources location="/css/**" mapping="/resources/css/"/>
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You inverted the two attributes. `locations` is where the files are in the web app root. `mapping` is the url-pattern used to access the resources from the browser. So the configuration should be

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/css/" mapping="/css/**"/>
```

As explained in [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-config-static-resources).

Comment: changed that but still getting a 404.

Comment: Where is this in the documentation? The front page of the docs isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: @bschlueter That's why I didn't link to the front page, but to the specific section of the documentation dealing with this configuration. Give your browser some time to load the full, long page.

Answer (score 2):

You have your resources in "resources" folder, so you added following line in dispatcher xml.

```
<mvc:resources location="/css/**" mapping="/resources/css/"/>
```

And this resources folder must have been in "webcontent" folder.
Then you need to access the resources by using context path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/elements.css">
```

Give this a try. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake .. using c:url to publish the absolute path helped :)

I am now publishing my URLs as

```
&lt;link rel="stylesheet" href="&lt;c:url value="/css/slideshow.css" />">
```

Comment: Is that answer a typo or is there not a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using locations relative to root context of Tomcat, then you need to do it like this.  The difference between this and the other answers is that I am including the application context in the location mapping:

```
<mvc:resources location="/webapp-name/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

The attribute "mapping" is relative to classpath whereas "location" is relative to root of Tomcat.  (NOTE: these are not 'relative' urls)

This config will provide access to resources in sub-folders, such as `/resources/css/*`