# Form is not getting submit after clicking on button

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Please check the below code:

Updated web.xml is:

```
<display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  </web-app>
```

thats why the UI messed up.
  link:
http://postimg.org/image/cf80ko6in/
and spring-servlet.xml is:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hrportal.controller" />
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
            </bean>

I do not know how to handle this warnings for error:404:
```

logs for server and I am getting error '404' on browser's console..

```
12:42:40,416 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:766 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/HRportal/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js]
12:42:40,417  WARN PageNotFound:1020 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HRportal/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
12:42:40,418 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:881 - Successfully completed request
12:42:40,419 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:766 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/HRportal/images/dataZen_Logo.png]
12:42:40,420  WARN PageNotFound:1020 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HRportal/images/dataZen_Logo.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
12:42:40,421 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:881 - Successfully completed request
12:42:40,497 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:766 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/HRportal/images/facebook-icon.png]
12:42:40,499  WARN PageNotFound:1020 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HRportal/images/facebook-icon.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
12:42:40,499 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:881 - Successfully completed request
12:42:40,501 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:766 - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/HRportal/images/imagestwitter.png]
12:42:40,503  WARN PageNotFound:1020 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HRportal/images/imagestwitter.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
12:42:40,527 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:881 - Successfully completed request
```

I am not able to solve these warnings.

Comment: $(this) is the button refernce it does not hav action,it should be `$("#loginForm").attr("action");`

Comment: even I tried this var str=("#formID").serialize(); but did not work for me.

Comment: Instead of $form.attr("action") this give url i.e. upcomingLeaves.do

Comment: yes that one also tried(ur:"upcomingLeaves.do",) did not work.

Comment: change url: $form.attr("action") to url: upcomingLeaves.do

Comment: Please check the buttons and tell me If I wrote something wrong.

Comment: @patilharshal16,Yes I tried but not working.

Comment: url: '<c:url value="/upcomingLeaves" />'

Your request mapping is not working so try with this now.

Comment: @patilharshal16,NO this <c:url/> is also not working.

Comment: Yes brother it work with <c:url value=""/>. because i always use this approach and it works like a champ.

Comment: @patilharshal16,see my url pattern in web.xml is <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>,so I map the url in controller class like.....@RequestMapping(value = "/upcomingLeaves")

Comment: also change in data.
data: $("#loginForm").serialize()

Comment: @patilharshal16,.......And action url in form tag is... action="upcomingLeaves.do" ..........so this always matches...so <c:url> ....may work but <c:url value="/upcomingLeaves" /> ........and <c:url value="upcomingLeaves.do" /> both are not working

Comment: do I need to remove type="button" in<button type="button"></button>

Comment: please remove old jsp and controller code from question, keep only what you have now, and make simple, else you will receive downvotes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done some mistakes:

**1)** you have form action as `upcomingLeaves.do`

```
<form:form commandName="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="upcomingLeaves.do">
```

and in Controller you have `/upcomingLeaves`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upcomingLeaves" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

**2)** you trying to get form but initialized with button.

```
$("button").click(function(){
         var $form = $(this); ....
```

**3)** I think you'd suppose to submit a form with one upcomingLeave once, But you have all the upcomingLeaves in single form. So when you submit the form, then Jquery will serialize  all upcomingLeaves.

**4)** In your case you supposed to perform actions like: `Accept` , `Reject` and `Cancel`, then no need of `$form.serialize()`, you can perform these action by sending employee id itself.

---

**Solution:**
Render anchor tags with employee id. and make the job simpler..

Like:

```
<a class="emp-leave-action"
   href='<c:url value="/leaveaccept.do/${upComLeave.employee_id}"/>'>Accept</a>
<a class="emp-leave-action"
   href='<c:url value="/leavereject.do/${upComLeave.employee_id}"/>'>Reject</a>
<a class="emp-leave-action"
   href='<c:url value="/leavecancel.do/${upComLeave.employee_id}"/>'>Cancel</a>
```

and implement GET methods like:
Accept:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/leaveaccept.do/{empId}" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processAccept(@PathVariable("empId") Integer empId) {

    //do emplyee leave accept work here
}
```

Reject:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/leavereject.do/{empId}" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processReject(@PathVariable("empId") Integer empId) {

    //do emplyee leave reject work here
}
```

Cancel:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/leavecancel.do/{empId}" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processCancel(@PathVariable("empId") Integer empId) {

    //do emplyee leave cancel work here
}
```

and finally use AJAX call like:

```
$("a.emp-leave-action").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.get( $(this).attr('href'), function( data ) {      
      alert( "action was performed." );
    });
});
```

Comment: My url pattern in web.xml is<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern> thats why I write like upcomingLeaves.do

If write /leaveaccept/{empId} (@PathVariable("empId"))then It says....The Attribute value is undefined for the Annotation Type@pathVAriable...

Comment: then, change all `/leavecancel.do/{empId}` in `@RequestMapping` and in anchor tag href too.

Comment: Now I am getting ......"The requested resource (/HRportal/upcomingLeaves.do/103) is not available."...error please help me...

Comment: please update your question with modified code, after have look what you doing will get know.

Comment: @user3264841 check answer updated, wrong you did is: your method is `POST` type change to `GET` and `@PathVariable` also update as in my answer, please look carefully to my answer

Comment: Do I Need to change so Beans in servlet.xml for RequestMappling...?Because Unfortunately,It's not working..... I did the same way you answered....and same error persist...

Comment: which version spring do you use? and it should work if you mapped to `*.do` in dispatcher.

Comment: create a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) with your spring configuration file and web.xml and the codes. and give me link will see where is the error.

Comment: ,Now I have both url-patterns ...but new issue is picture after putting  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> on web.xml my web application look(UI) has broken down

Comment: which url you making request and what you have mapped in controller.

Comment: The same url that you suggested me.....but I removed .do...now the url is../leaveaccept/{empId} and it wrking...because I have added the new url pattern in web.xml

Comment: remove `*.do` mapping when you have mapped with `/`, it will unused.

Comment: I am getting this warnings on console...WARN PageNotFound:1020 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/HRportal/images/imagestwitter.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: I need both url patterns for my web-aap.

Comment: you have to set resource handler to the location where css, img, js files are exists..

Comment: `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` add this with your folder location.. then in img src use `<c:url..` or `<spring:url..` have look to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101848/spring-mvc-resources)